# Opacity animation does not work in Angular, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

**Scenario:** I'm trying to animate an error message when there is a problem with the connection to the server; I've succeeded in animating a part of it, which makes the text move upon resizing the window.

Now, when the connection is back in place, I want to make the error message to change and then make it disappear after about a second (animate the opacity from 100% to 0%).

Everything works except the opacity part... Ideally I'd like the text element to disappear from the DOM as well, but as of now even the opacity animation doesn't work...

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

**TypeScript Code:**

```
animations: [
    trigger("changeWindowSize", [
      state(
        "open",
        style({
          top: "11px"
        })
      ),
      state(
        "close",
        style({
          top: "76px"
        })
      ),

      transition("open=>close", animate("200ms ease-in")),
      transition("close=>open", animate("200ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)"))

    ]),
    trigger("changeOpacity", [
      state(
        "opacity-1",
        style({
          opacity: "1"
        })
      ),
      state(
        "opacity-0",
        style({
          opacity: "0"
        })
      ),
      transition("opacity-1=>opacity-0", animate("200ms 1000ms ease-in")),
      transition("opacity-0=>opacity-1", animate("200ms 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)"))
    ])
  ]
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<mat-toolbar id="com-err" *ngIf="wsService.getConnectionError()" (window:resize)="onResize($event)"
             [@changeWindowSize]="windowWidthCurrent > 1240 ? 'open': 'close'">
  <mat-icon
    [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red', 'margin-left': '10px', 'margin-right': '10px', 'transform': 'scale(1.2)'}">
    warning
  </mat-icon><div>No Connection</div>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-toolbar id="com-err" *ngIf="!wsService.getConnectionError()" (window:resize)="onResize($event)"
             [@changeWindowSize]="windowWidthCurrent > 1190 ? 'open': 'close'"
             [@changeOpacity]="'opacity-1'">
  <mat-icon
    [ngStyle]="{'color': 'green', 'margin-left': '10px', 'margin-right': '10px', 'transform': 'scale(1.2)'}">
    warning
  </mat-icon><div>Connection Reestablished</div>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Where are you changing the state of `@changeOpacity` to `'opacity-0'`? It looks like it's just hardcoded to `'opacity-1'`.